# Multiple Routing Prefixes + loginAction Not Working

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.2

I have searched and though people have asked similar if not the exact same question on this site and elsewhere, several of those questions have gone unanswered and the rest simply don't apply to me (different error, old cake version, etc).

I have two routing prefixes set up in my core.php. Those are 'admin' and 'moderate'. I want ALL users to login via `/users/login` and be redirected afterwards to `/account`.

When I go to a standard (non-prefixed) page that requires authentication such as `/account`, then I am redirected to `/admin/users/login` (I do not want the prefix).

After I login I am successfully redirected to `/account`. (At least that part is working)

Here is my AppController code

```
public $components = array('Session',
   'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array('prefix' => false, 'admin' => false, 'moderate' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'loginRedirect' => array('prefix' => false, 'admin' => false, 'moderate' => false, 'controller' => 'account', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'index', 'prefix' => false, 'admin' => false, 'moderate' => false),
        'authError' => "You can't access that page",
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
); // components
```

I also tried changing all the '**false**' to '**null**'. No dice. I'm using CakePHP 2.2.4

**EDIT AS OF 2/11/14**
Because people are still answering I just wanted to note that this question is RESOLVED. I never figured out what the exact issue was so I never posted an official/accepted answer. I suspect it was an issue with my routing. The AppController code I provided above was correct.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `prefix` option it should work fine even without it. Also a little suggestion as a convention is to move the routing params ti the form as this way it is more readable:

`'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false, 'moderate' => false)`

@bowlerae try removing the `prefix` if it doesn't run then I'd be happy to chekc the full codebase out and help more.

Comment: It was originally without all of `'prefix' => false, 'admin' => false, 'moderate' => false` and it did not work. I tried just now removing just `'prefix' => false` and keeping the rest (`'admin' => false, 'moderate' => false`) and it still did not work. Also, sometimes after successful log in it redirects me to `/account`, sometimes it redirects me to `/admin/account` and sometime it redirects me to `/users/login` (requiring a second login)

Comment: It could be a session problem since wheather or not a user is an admin is stored as a value in the session and Cake uses it. If you've just logged out as an admin and then logged in as a regular user and at the same time for some reason your session is somehow still there you will be redirected to the right place. Check your session, maybe there is something wrong there such that the session persists.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. Also, if I try to access the page `/users/login` directly, it redirects me to `/admin/users/login` and again says that I can't access that page. After I login it redirects me back to the original page I was trying to access which would be `/users/login` but this page should be for guests only. My username is displaying on the screen with a welcome message so it's not like the login was unsuccessful. I did not have these issues before prefix routing.

Comment: Can you provide some code that I can run and test/debug?

Comment: what pages do you need?

Comment: In any case all would be best + DB. In this case I could do with AppController, AccountController, UsersController (+Views and Models), DB dump + exact Cake Core version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29902/discussion-between-borislav-sabev-and-bowlerae)

Comment: I've done a lot of editing of different pages simply working around and ignoring the issues. Well apparently one of the edits fixed my problem but I'm not sure which. I believe it was a routing issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
$this->Auth->loginAction = '/users/login';
```

Hopes that help!

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in AppController.Hope that help.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login','admin' => false, 'prefix' => false, 'moderate' => false);
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login','admin' => false, 'prefix' => false, 'moderate' => false);
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home','admin' => false, 'prefix' => false, 'moderate' => false);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I actually never figured out what the issue was, it "all of a sudden" started working again. Of course, not automagically, I must've done something that fixed it but I have no idea what. It wasn't working for about a week and then it started. I think it was an issue in my routing. The code in my AppController is correct.

Answer (score 0):

#### CakePHP 3 answer

In your [`APP/src/Controller/AppController.php`](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/src/Controller/AppController.php#L48):

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'loginAction' => [
        'prefix' => false, // tells the app not to use any prefix
        'controller' => 'Users', // change to your preference
        'action' => 'login', // change to your preference
    ],
    // loginRedirect, logoutRedirect etc.
    // …
]);
```

This is way more flexible and future-proof than blacklisting individual prefixes, as you may not know upfront what those may or may not be.

Confirmed this works with my CakePHP. Tested by removing `'prefix' => false`, it makes the app redirect to the prefixed login page, e.g. `/admin/users/login`, restoring that line fixes it back.

#### Official documentation

- [Authentication Handlers](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) → <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> "*loginAction*"
- [Prefix Routing](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) → <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> "*Leave a prefix*"